# Storing a json post request in variables in python

Tags: python, json, post, request

I am sending a json post request in Python and I am getting two return dictionary values but they are stored in one object.

This is what I have:

```
import json
import requests

def call():
    pay = {'token' : "4593543"}
    r = requests.post('https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges', params=pay)
```

I am getting two values store in the `r` object.

```
'{"needle":"qvsmbjkc", "haystack": ["pgunkqay","qvsmbjkc","qgswmzin","arwokfjm","taskzcup","yjvcabgr","xcrsldof","tecipvzf","cjtahlqb","pqgykrcz","ufyjrpad","hqezmcwl","fsyimbxr","tosqznha","lzujpvob","mbfsikde","nqvpjbhi","uwsqybai","ozetipqw","imancdqr"]}'
```

A *needle* and *haystack* value but they are both in the `r` object. How can I separate them into different variables?

Comment: Your question is badly formatetd. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40338796/edit) the question, select the code in it, click the `{}` button to format the code as code. Use the preview below the textbox to see what it it will look like.

Comment: You should be calling the `r.json()` method to extract the JSON object .

Comment: Thank you, so I got the needle string to be stored in a variable but when I stored the array in a variable, it stores it as an entire string instead of an index of strings. Is there a way I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` as a json-Method to read json responses directly into python structures:

```
r = requests.post('https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges', params=pay)
response = r.json()
print(response['needle'])
```

Comment: Thank you, so I got the needle string to be stored in a variable but when I stored the array in a variable, it stores it as an entire string instead of an index of strings. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: @Jack: Have you tried? No, `response['haystack']` is a list of strings.